# unrecognized selector sent to instance-Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, swift4

Hello All: i have a function that hit API to download data (LAT,LONG)and it works 100% fine. but the problem is i want to recall this function every 5 second and after i add a timer to do that every time i try to run it run very well and after 5 second i got crash

```
unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ffa4a51cb00
2018-07-20 11:05:31.191467+0200 Interactive Bus[684:6752] *** 
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
reason: '-[Interactive_Bus.MapVC 
downloadBusDataWithUserId:warning:delegate:completed:]: unrecognized 
selector sent to instance 0x7ffa4a51cb00'
```

i try to clean then build and there is no Code Error i have no idea why this crash happens

this is my Model Class

```
//  busLocationModel.swift
//  Interactive Bus
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class busLocationModel {

var route_pins: String?
var busLatitude: Double?
var busLongitude: Double?

@objc func downloadBusData(userId: String,warning: @escaping (String,String,String) -> Void, delegate : MapVC ,completed : @escaping DownloadCompleted) {

    let Parameters = ["parent_id": userId]
    print(#function)
    Alamofire.request(busLocationUrl, method: .get, parameters: Parameters).responseJSON { (response) in

        switch response.result {

        case .failure(let error):

            print(error)

            let alertControllerTitle = "Warning"
            let actionButtonTitle = "Ok"
            let alertMessage = "Some Thing Went Wrong Please Try Agin Later "

            return warning(alertControllerTitle, actionButtonTitle, alertMessage)

        case .success(let Value):

            let json = JSON(Value)
            //print(json)

            let status = json["status"].boolValue

            if status != false {

                for locations in json["data"].arrayValue {

                    let busPins = locations["route_pins"].stringValue
                    let bus_lat = locations["bus_lat"].doubleValue
                    let bus_long = locations["bus_long"].doubleValue

                    delegate.busPins = busPins
                    delegate.currentBusLate = bus_lat
                    delegate.currentBusLong = bus_long

                    print(delegate.busPins ?? "HH")
                    print("the bus lat is \(bus_lat)")
                    print("the bus long is \(bus_long)")
                }

            }
        }
        completed()
    }
}
}
```

and my Const is :

```
typealias DownloadCompleted = () -> ()
```

and My MapVC is :

```
//
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class MapVC: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak private var busMapView: MKMapView!

var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
//var locationManager: CLLocationManager!
let authorizationStatus = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()
fileprivate let regionRadius: Double = 1000 //Meter's From UP,Right,Down and Left
fileprivate var busInfoObject: busLocationModel!

var busPins: String!
var currentBusLate: CLLocationDegrees?
var currentBusLong: CLLocationDegrees?

var callFuncTimer: Timer!



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    locationManager.delegate = self
    busMapView.delegate = self
    busInfoObject = busLocationModel()

    let myActivity = CreatActivityIndicator()


    busInfoObject.downloadBusData(userId: "366", warning: DisplayAlertMessage, delegate: self) {

        self.drawLine()
        self.RemoveActivityIndicator(ActivityIndicator: myActivity)

        guard let latitude = self.currentBusLate else { return }
        guard let longitude = self.currentBusLong else { return }

        let Location = CLLocation(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)

        self.centerMapOnBusLocation(location: Location)

        self.callFuncTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5, target: self, selector: #selector(self.busInfoObject.downloadBusData(userId:warning:delegate:completed:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    }
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(true)

    configureLocationServices()
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(true)

    callFuncTimer.invalidate()
}

@IBAction func centerMapBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    if authorizationStatus == .authorizedAlways {

        guard let latitude = self.currentBusLate else { return }
        guard let longitude = self.currentBusLong else { return }

        let Location = CLLocation(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)

        centerMapOnBusLocation(location: Location)
    }
}
}
extension MapVC: MKMapViewDelegate {

fileprivate func centerMapOnBusLocation(location: CLLocation) {

    //guard let currtntLocationCoordinate = locationManager.location?.coordinate else { return }
    let coordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location.coordinate , regionRadius * 2.0, regionRadius * 2.0)
    busMapView.setRegion(coordinateRegion, animated: true)
}


func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {

    if (overlay is MKPolyline) {
        let pr = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay)
        pr.strokeColor = UIColor.blue
        pr.lineWidth = 5
        return pr
    }
    return MKPolylineRenderer()
}
}

extension MapVC {

func drawLine() {

    let coordinates = busPins.components(separatedBy: "#").dropFirst().map { (pin) -> CLLocationCoordinate2D in
        let latLng = pin.components(separatedBy: ",").map{ CLLocationDegrees($0)! }
        return CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latLng[0], longitude: latLng[1])
    }

    let polyLine = MKPolyline(coordinates: coordinates , count: coordinates.count)
    self.busMapView.add(polyLine)
}

}

extension MapVC: CLLocationManagerDelegate {

fileprivate func configureLocationServices() {

    if authorizationStatus == .notDetermined {
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    } else {

        return
    }
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {

    guard let latitude = self.currentBusLate else { return }
    guard let longitude = self.currentBusLong else { return }

    let Location = CLLocation(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)

    centerMapOnBusLocation(location: Location)
}
}
```

and this is DisplayAlertMessage:

```
    func DisplayAlertMessage(alertControllerTitle: String , actionButtonTitle: String , alertMessage: String) -> Void{


    let alertcontroller = UIAlertController(title: alertControllerTitle, message: alertMessage , preferredStyle: .alert)

    let okaction = UIAlertAction(title: actionButtonTitle, style: .default, handler: nil)

    alertcontroller.addAction(okaction)
    self.present(alertcontroller, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I can see no code Error i do the @OBJC the selector syntax is right but i still get the Error (unrecognized selector sent to instance) can you help me with that??

Comment: waht is the  "DisplayAlertMessage"  in parameters of the invoked method ?

Comment: still the Same issue and the same crash Error (unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ffa4a51cb00)

Comment: DisplayAlertMessage:
    func DisplayAlertMessage(alertControllerTitle: String , actionButtonTitle: String , alertMessage: String) -> Void{
        
        
        let alertcontroller = UIAlertController(title: alertControllerTitle, message: alertMessage , preferredStyle: .alert)
        
        let okaction = UIAlertAction(title: actionButtonTitle, style: .default, handler: nil)
        
        alertcontroller.addAction(okaction)
        self.present(alertcontroller, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In target-action pattern, the target object needs to implement the action method.

But in your code:

```
self.callFuncTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5, target: self, selector: #selector(self.busInfoObject.downloadBusData(userId:warning:delegate:completed:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

You use `self` as target, which is an instance of `MapVC`, that does not implement the method `downloadBusData(userId:warning:delegate:completed:)`.

When you specify `#selector(someInstance.methodName(...))` for the action method, you need to pass `someInstance` to the target object. In your case `someInstance` is `self.busInfoObject`.

Which means the line creating a `Timer` should become like this:

```
self.callFuncTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5, target: self.busInfoObject, selector: #selector(self.busInfoObject.downloadBusData(userId:warning:delegate:completed:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

But this does not work.

---

I was stupid enough that I have almost forgotten to tell you another important thing in target-action pattern.

Which is,

**The signature of the action method is definitely fixed according to the target.**

When using [`Timer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer), the signature needs to be the same as this:

[`class func scheduledTimer(timeInterval: TimeInterval, target: Any, selector: Selector, userInfo: Any?, repeats: Bool) -> Timer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer/1412416-scheduledtimer)

> `- (void)timerFireMethod:(NSTimer *)timer`

The notation is in Objective-C format, but the action method for `Timer` needs to have one and only one argument of type `Timer` (it's `NSTimer` in Objective-C.)

So, you may need to define a method matches the signature in your `MapVC`:

```
func timerFired(_ timer: Timer) {
    self.busInfoObject.downloadBusData(userId: ...,
                                       warning: {_, _, _ in
                                           ...
                                       }, 
                                       delegate: self,
                                       completed: {
                                           ...
                                       })
}
```

And change the line setting the timer to:

```
self.callFuncTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5, target: self, selector: #selector(self.timerFired(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Sorry, for showing you an incomplete answer, please try with filling `...` in my updated code.

Comment: Now after try this i still get crash but it is not (unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ffa4a51cb00) it is now empty log???

Comment: I have not tested your code completely so your code may have many other faults. If you get no more _unrecognized selector_ you should better start a new thread with your latest code in it.

Comment: Ok thank you so much i will try to figure out what is the reason of the new crash. thank you so much

Comment: Oh, I have found other faults in your code that I should have found it before I write the answer. Please stop starting a new thread.

Comment: OOPer thank you so so much now it is work 100% right without any crash's or error's thank you so much for your excellent explanation and your perfect answers

Answer (score 1):

Mistakes you have done here are

1. You are passing target as self that means your selector should be in MapVC
2. The selector you are passing is incorrect. According to Apple docs your selector should have signature

   -(void)timerFireMethod:(NSTimer *)timer

Refer this https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer/1412416-scheduledtimer

So to make it work do this:

```
func timerFireMethod(_ timer: Timer?) {

   self.busInfoObject.downloadBusData(your parameters)

}
```

// Register timer

```
self.callFuncTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5, target: self, selector: #selector(self.timerFireMethod), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

To make it easy you can use this method

```
self.callFuncTimer = Timer(timeInterval: 5, repeats: true, block: { (timer) in
            print("timer")
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Your settled target for timer is wrong. You should set function for timer and call.

```
func timerUpdates(_ timer : Timer)
{ 
  self.busInfoObject.downloadBusData(userId:warning:delegate:completed:)
}
self.callFuncTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5, target:#selector(self.timerUpdates:) self, selector: #selector(), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Comment: this Display 8 Error and 1 warning

Comment: In my case it was occurring because I forgot to change Module in Custom Class (Main.storyboard) because I reused a project for a new one

Answer (score 0):

Your invokation of the method missing some parameters

```
func downloadBusData(userId: String,warning: @escaping (String,String,String) -> Void, delegate : MapVC ,completed : @escaping DownloadCompleted)
```

as per your declaration it should have  userId,warning,delegate and the completion handler

Answer (score 0):

When you call function for every 5 seconds replace with this line and Please follow the convention of Swift. Write First letter capital for class name.

```
self.callFuncTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5, target: self, selector: #selector(BusLocationModel.downloadBusData(userId:warning:delegate:completed:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Comment: Still the same error (unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9ff9d198d0)

Comment: Fire a callFuncTimer timer.